# How to turn multiple vue components into one single npm package?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component

I was told by the project manager at the company I work for to take all the global components of a vue project we're working on and turning them into a single npm package that anyone working on the project can import and start using. essentially I have to take the global components and turn them into a component library like vuetify which is installed using npm and than imported from node modules directory.

[image]

I was wondering if you guys could point me in the right direction on how to achieve this. thanks in advance.

Comment: https://medium.com/justfrontendthings/how-to-create-and-publish-your-own-vuejs-component-library-on-npm-using-vue-cli-28e60943eed3 that might help you

Answer (score 2):

So, regardless of the implementation, the main thing you need is following this guide on how to create an npm package 
https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-private-packages

**Then**

You create an src folder.
In the src, you will create a folder named "components" with all your -duh- components.

In the src folder, you will also create an index.js file, from there you will export your components.

```
export { default as VDataTable } from './components/VDataTable.vue'
// ...etc
```

**Option1**

If you use a bundler for your projects, and you know by a fact that all your codebases will use a bundler, you can simply create a folder with a package.json.

In your package.json then you will

```
  "module": "src/index.js",
  "main": "src/index.js"
```

In this scenario, you are letting your main project bundler (which is using the package) transpile all the packages for you, (babel, single file components)

**Option 2**

In case you have absolutely no clue of the nature of the projects which can use your library you will need a bundler for your components.

An example can be Rollup.

I suggest these 2 guides.

https://rollupjs.org/

https://rollup-plugin-vue.vuejs.org/

Long story short, Rollup will transpile for you the files you requested (js and css), and you will have to make them available from your package.json

```
  "module": "src/dist/library.esm.js",
  "main": "src/library.common.js"
```

And then you can release your package. Possibly privately or you might get fired :P